# How can I efficiently delete extra details of this model?

Tags: scripting, unity, gltf

I received multiple STEP files containing models of hardware. I converted these to gltf and imported the result in blender. The models contain ~7.7M triangles, because every nut and bolt is modeled in detail.

My end goal is to have a simplified mesh that I can import into Unity. I would like to delete all details of the model that are internal components (think, a model of a car without the detail of an engine under the hood).

The first issue that I believe I have, is under the Outliner > Scene Collection, there are many Empty Objects that only serve to apply a rotation and position delta to their child objects. If I were to filter for something such as "M5" to get all size M5 screws/nuts/bolts my next step was to press A with the cursor over the Outliner to select everything. The problem is this also selects the parent Empty Object, which does have other children. If I delete this, then it causes other objects to move and rotate after being unparented.

[image: Selecting all M5]

[image: Lost rotation and position]

I have 6 variations of this model, all of which need to undergo the same process. Another attempt I made was to select all of the parts of the model that I would like to keep, and then Inverting the selection before deleting. The downside to this is that while I know things I want to remove, I am not 100% sure of everything that needs to stay. Some of the parts of the frame can be removed, but others I would like to leave as a reference for when I simplify the overall geometry.

After the removal of details that do not need to be represented in Unity, I would still need to fill in the holes left by the missing screws. I had some success using the 'Edit Mode > Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes / Decimate Geometry' tools, but it was a very tedious process because I had to work individually on every screw hole.

[image: Fill Holes]

Update: I realized that if I select objects and move them to a different collection it does not break their position / rotation. This way I was able to quickly select the obvious parts to keep, as well as toggle between the two views to find more subtle details that I would still want to keep in final model. If possible, I would still like to automate this process through scripts.